# Conditional ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (Update only if certain condition is true)

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have the following query being used:

```
INSERT INTO userlist (username, lastupdate, programruncount, ip)
VALUES (:username, NOW(), 1, :ip)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
lastupdate = NOW(), programruncount = programruncount + 1, ip = :ip;
```

However, I also want to make the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` conditional, so it will do the following:

- **IF** `lastupdate` was less than 20 minutes ago (`lastupdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE`).
- **True:** Update `lastupdate = NOW()`, add one to `programruncount` and then update `ip = :ip`.
- **False:** All fields should be left the same.

I am not really sure how I would do this but after looking around, I tried using an `IF` Statement in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part.

```
INSERT INTO userlist (username, lastupdate, programruncount, ip)
VALUES ("testuser", NOW(), "1", "127.0.0.1")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
IF(lastupdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE, VALUES(lastupdate, programruncount + 1),
lastupdate, programruncount);
```

However I am getting the following error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(lastupdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE, VALUES(lastupdate, programruncount +' at line 6`

Comment: I bet everyone who comes here is doing it to protect their site from these annoying automated attacks (SQL-Injection scripts, etc.)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

you're using IF statement and VALUES() function incorrectly

```
INSERT INTO userlist (username, lastupdate, programruncount, ip)
VALUES (:username, NOW(), 1, :ip)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
lastupdate = IF(NOW() > lastupdate + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE, NOW(), lastupdate),
programruncount = IF(NOW() > lastupdate + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE, programruncount + 1,   programruncount),
ip = IF(NOW() > lastupdate + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE, VALUES(ip), ip);
```

so IF checks for a condition and return one of two values provided as its parameters. See [MySQL's Flow Control Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

Comment: This is leaving the fields the same, but it's still doing an update either way. Is there a way to do nothing if the last update condition is not met?

Answer (score 0):

i always do it this way:

> INSERT INTO userlist (username, lastupdate, programruncount, ip)
> VALUES (:username, NOW(), 1, :ip)
>
> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>
> lastupdate = IF(lastupdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE, NOW(), lastupdate),
>
> programruncount = IF(lastupdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE, programruncount + 1,   programruncount),
>
> ip = IF(lastupdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE, **VALUE(ip), ip**);

VALUE(ip) --> update with new value

ip --> will not update the field

Comment: 1. it's not value() but values() 2. It's already deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I made a shocking discovery regarding the INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. If the values of some fields in the UPDATE clause depend on the original value of another field, the order of the fields is crucial.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (primari_key_column, column_datetime, column3, column4)
     VALUES ('primari_key_value', 'datetime_value', 'value3', 'value4') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column3 = IF(column_datetime <= 'datetime_value', 'value3', column3)
                      , column4 = IF(column_datetime <= 'datetime_value', 'value4', column4)
                      , column_datetime = IF(column_datetime <= 'datetime_value', 'datetime_value', column_datetime);
```

The example shows the correct usage, i.e. the field to be modified last is the field whose value determines whether the new values are to be placed in the affected row or whether the old values are to remain in it.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (primari_key_column, column_datetime, column3, column4)
     VALUES ('primari_key_value', 'datetime_value', 'value3', 'value4') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column_datetime = IF(column_datetime <= 'datetime_value', 'datetime_value', column_datetime)
                      , column3 = IF(column_datetime <= 'datetime_value', 'value3', column3)
                      , column4 = IF(columnn_datetime <= 'datetime_value', 'value4', column4);
```

In this **INCORRECT** case, only the modification of the *column_datetime* field takes place, the others don't because the condition is no longer met afterwards.

This behaviour is definitely the case for AWS RDS Aurora 5.7 (MySQL 5.7.12).