# Locking mechanism implemented using the database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to implement a locking mechanism using the following MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE Locker (
  `Id` int(11), 
  `locked_until` timestamp null,
  unique index `unique` (`Id` asc)
);
```

The idea is that there will be multiple processes that receive `id`s to process. The processing itself takes place outside of MySQL, but I would like to use the database table to keep track of the processing currently being done and disallow the same `id` being processed concurrently.

My idea is the following:

- given an `id` I will insert (or update) a corresponding record in the table, setting `locked_until` to a sensible value (usually `CURRENT TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 SECOND)
- do the processing outside MySQL
- when the item is processed, `UPDATE Locker SET locked_until=null WHERE id={current_id}`

I'm having trouble with the first bullet in the list, as there are three distinct cases to handle:

- a row does not exist for `id` ==> should insert
- a row already exists, but it's not locked (`locked_until` is either `null` or a value in the past) ==> should update with a new `locked_until` value
- a row already exists, but it's locked ==> should do nothing in the DB, but signal back to the program that the processing should not take place.

My current status is this:

```
insert into Locker (Id, locked_until)
values (3, current_timestamp + interval 60 second)
on duplicate key update locked_until = current_timestamp + interval 60 second;
```

But the problem with this is that it disregards currently updated rows. I cannot add a `WHERE` clause, as that's invalid syntax.

I would also attempt to do a [conditional update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588401/conditional-on-duplicate-key-update-update-only-if-certain-condition-is-true?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but I'm not sure how I would signal back to the calling program that the element is currently locked. (because `output` is not supported as in SQL Server)

Is it possible to do all this in a single statement?

---

#### Update:

I found a way to do it, but it feels hack-ish:

```
insert into Locker (Id, locked_until)
values (3, current_timestamp + interval 60 second)
on duplicate key update locked_until = if(locked_until < current_timestamp,
                                                current_timestamp + interval 60 second,
                                                'error');
```

In cases the second part of the `if` needs to be evaluated, the `'error'` value makes it explode, signalling that that particular item is currently locked.

I'm still looking for better/cleaner ways to do this though.

Comment: You can check the number of affected rows after  your `current status` query. For new Id it will be 1, while for updated existing record it will return 2. If Id exists and locked_until is not changed N of affected rows = 0. At least this is what I see on my old mariadb instance.

Comment: @YuriLachin The trouble is that if there's a locked record, the update takes place anyway. It's just a different value dependiing on the `if`. I cannot `UPDATE ... WHERE` after the `DUPLICATE KEY` unfortunately.

Comment: Do you get affected rows > 0 if you `SET locked_until = if(locked_until current_timestamp, current_timestamp + interval 60 second,locked_until)` ?

Comment: @YuriLachin You are right! Your solution works like a charm! You can post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Vatev You are right; Yuri's solution works fine. I was making a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the number of affected rows after your current status query. For new Id it will be 1, while for updated existing record it will return 2. If Id exists and locked_until is not changed N of affected rows = 0. At least this is what I see on my old mariadb instance.